# See More with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, template-lite

I retrieve comments from my database and show comments with character limit until 105

I use this code  `<td>{$users.COMMENT|truncate:105:"..."}</td>`

What i want is that if comment is bigger than 105 make truncate to 105 chacters and put a checkbox.if not do not put a checkbox.

and if user click the checkbox, row will be bigger and user will see the full comment.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

The HTML code:

```
 <div id="container">
     <input type="checkbox" onclick="javascrpt: $('#container').toggleClass('active')">
     <div class='comment_short'>short comment </div >
     <div class='comment_full'>very loooooong comment very loooooong comment  very loooooong comment  very loooooong comment </div >
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
div#container.active div.comment_full {
    display: block;
}

div#container div.comment_full {
    display: none;
}
```

Here the example http://jsfiddle.net/guTMs/1/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to use hidden elements.

```
<td>
 <span class='comment_short'>{$users.COMMENT|truncate:105:"..."}</span>
 <span class='comment_full' style='display:none'>{$users.COMMENT}</span>
</td>
```

Then when you click the checkbox, you toggle visibility on each element.

Answer (score 0):

Put remaining text in `<span style="display:none" id="more_text">` tag and on more button write following:

```
<button name="more" value="more" onclick="document.getElementById('more_text').style.display = 'block'">
```